# How to retain the set of images in jquery (jcarousel)

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am using jcarousel to show image as slides. 5 images are shown at a time and next button slides one image to right, there are a total of 9 images.
Each image is a link to its detailed page.
but now if click the last image to go to its detailed page and then come back to the page(using browser back button) the image slide shows the 1st 5 images.
But i have to retain the set of images that was present when i clicked the image. What must be done to do this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the start position.. See this example.. 
[Carousel with custom start position](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_start.html)

While clicking on the image, store the position to a cookie, and on return get the value from cookie and assign to the start option

Comment: i am using drupal, so its in a block n present in several other pages, i tried using cookie to set the start value, but once set through out the site the same set of images are displayed, i dont have any idea at what stage to unset the cookie.

Comment: If any how u can get the previous page url i can check it and unset the cookie if its the previous url is not the detailed page, i could not find a way to get the previous url (no back button provided in detailed page, browser back is the only option).

Comment: I have not much idea about drupal.. I think, it is possible to get the page name from block and based on that you can set the start position in javascript.

Comment: no it doesn concern with drupal, i was just saying that same stuff is present in many other pages also , so once cookie is set for the start parameter as 3, then on other pages also it starts with third image. so i need to unset the cookie if the previous page is not detailed page.

Comment: browser back button reloads the page, or is there any way to prevent that.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, and please do share any thoughts on this, have to go now, thanks again..

Comment: i ve tried cookie but got problem when to unset it , ok found out a way to append url with # and the value to start with, it works fine except for chrome, but its fine for now, thanks for ur answers.